# Tainting of constants in unpruned branches

Tags: perl, taint

Perl's apparent behavior is to taint constants in branches remaining after branch pruning based on a tainted condition. Is this documented?

This outputs `1`:

```
bash$ T="" perl -Tle '

use constant T=>$ENV{T};
use Scalar::Util qw/tainted/;
exit if T;
print tainted(0)'
```

It seems like the constant `0` is tainted because everything after the exit (in the original problem it was a return) is in a branch that remains after branch pruning has occurred based on a tainted condition. This happens to be a very nifty feature of Perl's taint mode, but I cannot find documentation for it anywhere. When `$ENV{T}` is not set or when the condition is on a dynamic access to `$ENV{T}`, constants are not tainted.

By the way, the best answer I know at this time to the associated implied actual software development problem from which this question arises, of *how do I turn off a section of taint-mode perl source at development time without tainting my constants*, is, set your constant to a constant instead of a tainted environment variable, like so:

```
use constant DEBUG_MODE => ( $ENV{DEV_DEBUG} ? 1 : 0 );
```

Comment: This may be fixed after 5.22 https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=122669

Answer (score 0):

the best answer I know at this time to the associated implied actual software development problem from which this question arises, of how do I turn off a section of taint-mode perl source at development time without tainting my constants, is, set your constant to a constant instead of a tainted environment variable, like so:

```
use constant DEBUG_MODE => ( $ENV{DEV_DEBUG} ? 1 : 0 );
```